# i have this error when i try to upload image to database in my flutter app

Tags: database, flutter, image

error: The name 'File' is defined in the libraries 'dart:html' and 'dart:io'.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Delete import ‘dart:html’; from your imports and only import dart:io

Comment: @HichemGuessab can you mark the answer as solved?